# Full screen page

Tags: html, fullscreen

I'have a problem for full screen bootstrap css web site.my web site is normally view but problem is google chrome or int.explorer usefull links bar.

How to set full screen together browser's usefull links bar ?

Comment: Please re word your question as it doesn't fully make sense, please also add your code

Answer (score 2):

To hide the scrollbar set
    overflow: hidden
on the element in your css.